# EclEmma Coverage checking using Eclipse

Tags: junit, code-coverage, eclemma

I want to check my test coverage of GWT codes using EclEmma, when i run coverage it always shows zero percentage of coverage in report.
Can any one help me out..
Below is the image of coverage report, it show i didn't cover any instructions, 
[image]

thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the EclEmma global filters are correct.

On `Preferences`, `Java`, `Code Coverage` it should show Includes: * and nothing in Excludes:

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PowerMock?

See [this](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/422) issue.

Comment: That content has moved.  Can you provide additional details or a new URL?